# how to deploy a next app where i am calling api routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having troubles while deploying my nextjs app to vercel where Iam calling my API routes thats localhost but in when deploy its in vercel I don't know what domain name will be so it's giving error for not fetehing datas.

Thanks for your help.
I highly appreciate you

Comment: what about using absolute URLs, e.g. `/api/my-endpoint`?

Comment: That's what I am thinking in development that's in localhost. But when when deploying I don't know what the name of domain will be what should I give? When fetching data from API routes.